# What can I do as ADC to keep pressure on mid-game, when the team just won't group for objectives?

Tags: league-of-legends

Lately I've been encountering this problem a lot in ranked gold V: mid game and beyond, when ahead the team won't group for objectives. For instance after taking the mid inhib, they either stay mid and achieve nothing, roam randomly alone or in groups of 2 in their jungle, chase/harass them in jungle.

I think this is very very bad, we aren't putting pressure on them. We could push for the other towers/inhib and they would have to defend 2 lanes. And even if we win some tf in the jungle we can't take anything else, because the lanes are not pushed and in mid there is nothing to do (except die to the 2 nexus towers). Multiple times I've lost games this way, even if we got a big lead on them early.

I try to tell them to push lanes, that there is no objectives mid. Nobody listens to me. Failing that I've tried to tell them to at least group as 5.

I absolutely don't know what to do at this point. Sometimes I just go alone for towers/inhibs. Sometimes this works, sometimes this backfires as they come and kill me.

Where to be, where to go as an ADC,  when we got mid inhib, 2 of them are mid lane doing God knows what, 1 is in our jungle farming and the other is in their jungle being "sneaky". And this goes on until the end of the game.

Comment: This question may attract opinion based answers. Since it's other humans rather than the game it's self giving you difficulty, its hard to say.

Comment: Is this an actual question or just a rant?

Comment: It is a question: what to do, where to position in such a situation.

Comment: League is a **very** team-oriented game as far as I understand (which admittedly isn't much, I've never played it), but what makes you think that there is something you can do solo to turn the tide when the team doesn't want to cooperate? From my understanding, you need good team communication and coordination, and if you aren't getting that (and you can't convince them to form up around someone or work for a united objective) then you're never going to get anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a few options here. I'm basing on the scenario that you presented in your last sentence:

> when we got mid inhib, 2 of them are mid lane doing God knows what, 1 is in our jungle farming and the other is in their jungle being "sneaky".

1. If you have a strong siege comp, such as Xerath, Azir, Veigar, Caitlyn, etc. it would be a lot better to just **group at mid and push down together with the super minion wave**. Although it may not result in a nexus turret immediately, you can slowly wear it down by **sieging** the twin turrets. This provides the opponent team with very limited options since if they don't properly defend the twin turrets, either or both of them are going to fall as super minions really do hit hard on the turrets. This kind of pressure is really hard on the enemies, and in uncoordinated games can prove disastrous.
2. If your team is compromising of teamfighting champions such as Malphite, Jinx, etc. it would be a good idea to **force a teamfight using an objective such as Baron/Dragon as a bait**. Ping the objective at hand, and ask your teammates to group near it. Start with the objective with vision around your team. Once you start seeing that enemies are reacting to your "bait", disengage from the objective and turn right back on them. If your team is ahead enough as you say, they should be able to win a 4v5 or even a 3v5 considering some of them as you have described is being "sneaky".
3. **Split Push**. Yes, even as an ADC, you can and you should split push, especially if your team is refusing 100% to group together. It's a good idea to have your support give you some vision in the side of the jungle that you're split pushing so that you can get out immediately if you see them coming for you. You should be putting down your own blue trinket as well as pink ward as well on your way to split pushing. This way, the enemies have 2 options: lose out on farm and time that can be better spent on capturing objectives and etc. or, send 2 or more of their members to the lane you're pushing, and waste valuable time.
4. **Just farm up**. In the case that no viable choices are there for any viable course of action (e.g. enemy team has strong global presence thus preventing you from split pushing, their teamfight is stronger than yours, and your comp is not good for sieging), the obvious thing would be to just farm. Initiate slow pushes on side lanes while getting some CS. Farm your own jungle, and farm opponent's jungle if you're sure that it's safe to do so. Get every single bit of gold in preparation for late game fights.

These options are definitely not every option you have, and the list is definitely not exhaustible. There are always something better to do, something else you can do every single game. Various factors such as the pace of the game, gold lead, team comps, etc. comes into play here.

I've tried to list down the most generic things you can do in the scenario, however, do remember again that this is extremely situational, and you alone has to decide what's best for each games.

Comment: Thank you. This is good advice. Am I right that generally pushing a lane with the inhib up is better than pushing a lane with the inhib already taken?

Comment: Sometimes pushing down a single lane with the help of super minions is better, sometimes trying to pressure other lanes is better. As I said, its all situational.